# How to show $F(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, define $F(x)=\int_a^bf(x+t)\cos t\,dt,x\in [a,b]$.

How to show $F(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$?

Comment: You need $f$ to be differentiable.

Comment: This is kind of like a convolution operator. If you take $u = x+t$ with $du =dt$ inside the integral, you can shift the $x$ dependence off $f$.

Answer (score 3):

$F(x)=\int_{a+x}^{b+x} f(s) [\cos \,s \cos \,x+\sin \,s \sin \,x]ds$. Split this into two terms and pull out $\cos\, x,\sin\,x$ from the integral. Use the fact indefinite integrals of continuous functions are differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

With $u=x+t$, we have

$F(x) = \int_{a+x}^{b+x}f(u)\cos(u-x)du$.

Now use liebniz integral rule

$F'(x) = f(b+x)\cos(b)-f(a+x)\cos(a)+\int_{a+x}^{b+x}f(u)\sin(u-x)du$